# How to change Jenkins environmental variable from 'Execute System Groovy Script'

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have this 'Execute system Groovy Script' in my Jenkins job (not pipeline)...

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import hudson.model.Environment

def process_type = build.properties.environment.PROCESSTYPE.toString();
def SDATE = build.properties.environment.START_DATE.toString();
def EDATE = build.properties.environment.END_DATE.toString();

         println "Old Dates :"    
         println "$SDATE"
         println "$EDATE"


if(process_type == "Nightly") {

    def today = new Date()
    def sevenDaysAgo = today - 7

    def START_DATE2 =   sevenDaysAgo.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    def END_DATE2 = today.format("yyyy-MM-dd")

    String START_DATE =  START_DATE2.toString()
    String END_DATE = END_DATE2.toString()

         println "New Dates :"    
         println "$START_DATE"
         println "$END_DATE"

        String vars = [START_DATE: "$START_DATE", END_DATE: "$END_DATE"]

  }
```

I may have more in it than I need, as using Groovy inside of a Jenkins job is new to me and I have been trying all kinds of things to get this to work.  Anyway, this Jenkins job can be run 'Nightly, and then would use a seven day date range, or it can be supplied with a date range. If 'Nightly', I want to set the 7 day date range (overwriting the two default dates), and then use the new dates in the next build step, which is a 'Execute Windows Batch command", and uses the arguments...'%START_DATE%' '%END_DATE%'.

The code above gets executed, but the windows step is still using the old default dates.  So,how do I change the environmental variable in the groovy step, and pass it back to Jenkins, so that the windows batch step gets the new values?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure that I am not using more API's than I need, but I have the following code working.  It appears that you cannot modify the values of an already existing Job Parameter, so I had to create a new one to be used in the next job step.  Here is the code...

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import hudson.model.Environment

def process_type = build.properties.environment.PROCESSTYPE.toString();
def SDATE = build.properties.environment.START_DATE.toString();
def EDATE = build.properties.environment.END_DATE.toString();

println "Old Dates :"    
println "$SDATE"
println "$EDATE"


EnvVars envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);

if(process_type == "Nightly") {

    def today = new Date()
    def sevenDaysAgo = today - 7

    def START_DATE2 =   sevenDaysAgo.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    def END_DATE2 = today.format("yyyy-MM-dd")

    String START_DATE =  START_DATE2.toString()
    String END_DATE = END_DATE2.toString()

         println "New Dates :"    
         println "$START_DATE"
         println "$END_DATE"

        File file = new File(envVars.get('WORKSPACE') + "\\Dates.txt")
        file.write "NEW_START_DATE=" + "$START_DATE" + "\r\n"
        file <<  "NEW_END_DATE=" + "$END_DATE" + "\r\n"
        println file.text
} else
{ 
       // The next step 'Inject Environment variables', requires this file to exist
       // if not a nightly run use date range provided in parameters

         println "New Old Dates :"    
         println "$SDATE"
         println "$EDATE"

       File file = new File(envVars.get('WORKSPACE') + "\\Dates.txt")
        file.write "NEW_START_DATE=" + "$SDATE" + "\r\n"
        file <<  "NEW_END_DATE=" + "$EDATE" + "\r\n"
        println file.text
}
```